# c# Get member name of dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have some JSON like this

```
{
    Something {
        Another {
            Key: "Value"
        }
    }
}
```

I convert that to a dynamic object using Newtonsoft.Json.
Let's say I want to Console.WriteLine the inner member of 'Something'. Meaning I want the value 'Another' written in the Console.

In another JSON file the child of 'Something' could be different, like 'AThird', then I want that name written.

I've tried alittle with some reflection, but can't seem to find the member name.

Comment: "I've tried alittle with some reflection" Show *what* you´ve tried. We don´t want to provide those solution you´ve allready tested and that doesn´t work for you.

Comment: `foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)yourobject.Something)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(property.Key);
  }`